# An answer which tells that the person asking the question is trying to cheat. Shall I delete this answer or not?

Tags: discussion

When I was reviewing close-votes queue, I came across this answer.

[image]

Now, this is not an answer for sure(can be put as comment but some people don't give attention to comments).

But deleting this answer will directly benefit person who is trying to cheat.

So, I chose to vote for deletion of the question instead. Hope I did right thing.

Just wanted opinion what should be done with **answers** in such cases? Delete them or keep them?

[Link to the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911715/count-subarrays-with-given-conditions)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does it answer the question? No. So it should be deleted. It should be a comment at best.

Does the question follow the site rules? Then there is actually no rule it can't be answered. If it isn't illegal (like the question having another license for example), there isn't much we can do, or should do.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is a non-answer and should be deleted. I suggest leaving no comment for the user; the templated "this does not provide an answer ... to critique or ask for clarification..." would be utterly out of place there.

The rest is up to you, but what I normally do is:

1. Repost the link to contest under the question as a comment, as it provides some context of the question.
2. If the site has a policy regarding questions from ongoing contests, follow it. (Some sites have such a policy, others do not.)